# Spark-Cosmosdb control parallelism/requests when querying small datasets to optimize RU cost

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Same issue with Spark2.4-cosmosdb and spark3-cosmosdb connector
Same issue with HDInsight and Synapse

We have a small collection in cosmosdb - few hundred documents.

A spark job running on HDInsight cluster (or Synapse) where this data is queried.

Query = select * from c where c.Mode != "anc" (partition key is Id  field) and hence this is a cross partition query, it actually hits all partition. But I believe fixing the partition key will not solve the problem at hand, it is a separate problem

Ideally this should be a small RU usage but I observe that more the number of executors, more the number of requests and hence high RU usage. I tried different scale configuration and could correlate more the number of executors, more the number of requests.

I enabled diagnostics on cosmosdb to get details on DataPlaneRequests. I see different nodes from same cluster are making the same request at the same time.

Question1- Is this because spark driver is giving this task to all available executors and since there is no partitioning in the result set, all executors endup doing the same work?

Question2 - How can this be controlled? One node should be able to handle this easily. Can this be enforced? The job as a whole needs more nodes for other actions but this particular action, if it can be curbed to one node.

Comment: Have you tried with the Throughput Control configuration? https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos-spark_3_2-12/docs/configuration-reference.md#throughput-control-config

Comment: I am on spark 2.4 and I believe throughput control is only for writes. https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark/wiki/Configuration-references

Comment: You mentioned you saw this on spark3-cosmosdb so if that is the case, then you could use the throughput control https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/throughput-control-spark. For Spark 3 connector, the distribution across executors is explained here https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos-spark_3_2-12/docs/scenarios/Ingestion.md